# Trello API ~ simply getting the contents of a list?

Tags: python, api, trello

I am trying to get the contents of a list on I a board I created to understand some things about my work flow.

The API seems quite complex, and I have been at it for hours. I have an API key, as well as a Secret key.

I tried the following from their docs: https://api.trello.com/1/lists/4eea4ffc91e31d174600004a/cards?key=[application_key]&token=[optional_auth_token]

However, I am not sure where these letters/numbers are coming from: `4eea4ffc91e31d174600004a`.

I read the following page: https://developers.trello.com/apis (which gave me the link to the url above), but there is no info on how to get `4eea4ffc91e31d174600004a`.

I simply want to visit a url that gives me json or something of that vein, with all the contents of a list (e.g. the cards + their names). Then I can visit that link programmatically and do my analysis.

Edit: Using the trello developer sandbox: https://developers.trello.com/sandbox/ I found the id of a list, which I substituted into `4eea4ffc91e31d174600004a`, but now I get the following: `Taco says “invalid token”, but what does he know? He's just a dog.`

I used the Secret key as the token, but I guess that's not the token. So the question boils down to how can I get a token?

Thanks

Comment: The python tag is misleading.

Answer (score 3):

So the full answer is:

To get the cards in a list, three things are required:

1. API Key
2. List ID
3. Token

(Secret key isn't needed anywhere)

To get the List ID, the simplest way to do that is to use the developer sandbox https://developers.trello.com/sandbox/ then hit 'get lists' + 'execute' and obtain the id of the list of interest.

Note if you have multiple boards, you will need to specify the board id here: `Trello.get('/boards/[board_id]/lists', success, error);`. You can get the board id by hitting 'get boards' + 'execute', then looking for the id of interest.

To get a token, you need to go here: https://trello.com/1/connect?key=[application_key]&name=MyApp&response_type=token

Then you can make the call:

https://api.trello.com/1/lists/[list_id]/cards?key=[application_key]&token=[optional_auth_token]

Comment: Use the sandbox to get the ids of the models you are looking for... wow. I started to lol/sob after that... I've spent the day trying to figure out an easy way to get these ids...

Answer (score 1):

I recently worked on Trello data using its RESTful API and using Python's py-trello. As the question is about accessing Trello list and its cards, will limit my solution to list access using Trello RESTful API and py-trello.

**1. Using Trello RESTful API:**

Following you need to form your URI to access the desired list and its cards JSON

i) API Key: You can get the key from https://trello.com/app-key

ii) Token: On the above page itself, you'll find link to the Token generation. Posting the snap shot below for convenience-

[image]

iii) list id: you can find this in the board JSON

Using these 3 items, below is how the RESTful URI to access a list is going to look like:

```
list_json_url = "https://api.trello.com/1/lists/replace_this_with_ur_list_id?cards=all&key=replace_this_with_ur_api_key&token=replace_this_with_your_token
```

Below is how i'm loading above list JSON in my Python program :

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(list_json_url) as fj:
    data = json.load(fj)
```

**2. Using py-trello:**

There can be better ways to do this using py-trello's filtering features, i have just taken this from my entire multi-boards analysis code and added a condition to match a list id:

```
from trello import TrelloClient

API_KEY = "XXXXXXX"
API_TOKEN = "XXXXXXXXXX"
client = TrelloClient(api_key=API_KEY, token=API_TOKEN)

for board in client.list_boards():
    for l in board.list_lists():
        if l.id = "ur_list_id":
          #do your list analysis here
```

Comment: I'm getting the error "cannot import name 'TrelloClient' from 'trello'"
I've first run "pip3 install py-trello"
and then "python3 trello.py", which only have one line: "from trello import TrelloClient"

Comment: Is "import trello" only working? If its working, see its __init__ has "from trello.trelloclient import *". I tested this on trello version 0.11.3

Answer (score 0):

That is the list id which you can get by an API call to the boards

You'll find details [here](https://developers.trello.com/apis#boards).

https://developers.trello.com/apis#boards

Comment: Toby, I got the list id using the developer sandbox. I used that in the url, but now I need a valid token. Is there a simple way to get that? I am not trying to create a web service or anything, just want to get some info

Comment: Toby, everything was a bit scattered all over the docs (for what seems to be a very simple/straightforward use-case), I posted a full answer below if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

## Go to link: https://trello.com/app-key

## Click in TOKEN

[image]

## Click in Allow

[image]

## Copy your token

[image]

## DONE